# Getting access to input value that are dynamicallu created in a shiny module

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny, module

I've created a Shiny app that works just fine but my next step is to create a module that allows other people who work with me to create apps that do the same without having to rewrite completely the code.

The main change would be on the numbers of numeric parameters that are asked as an input.
My goal was to create a module that has, as an input, a list of the parameters' name and the list of their label to create automatically numeric inputs with these names and labels.
The difficulty is that there is a numeric input that generate automatically multiple inputs for each parameter.
I've succeeded to create the UI part but I fail to get access to these inputs in the module to use them for the next part of my module.

My best try so far is :

```
library(shiny)
#example of list of names and labels that will be written by my colleagues
names_list <- c ("alpha","beta","gamma","delta")
labels_list <- c ("\\(\\alpha\\)","\\(\\beta\\)","\\(\\gamma\\)","\\(\\delta\\)")

parametresUI <-function(id){
  ns <-NS(id)
  tagList(fluidRow(numericInput(ns("nb"),label="number of steps",value=2,min=0)),
          fluidRow(uiOutput(ns("parametres"))),
          fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput(ns("value"))))
}

parametresServer <- function(id,names_list,labels_list){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    output$parametres <-renderUI({
      number_list<-as.list(1:input$nb)
      div(class = "dynamicSI",
          lapply(1:length(names_list),function(j){
            lapply(number_list, function(i) {
              fluidRow(column(3,
                              withMathJax(numericInput(inputId=paste0(names_list[j], i), label = paste0(labels_list[j], i),value=0,min=0)
                              )),
                       column(3,
                              withMathJax(numericInput(inputId=paste0("varia",names_list[j], i), label = paste0("\\(\\sigma\\)(",labels_list[j], i,")"),value=0,min=0)
                              )),
              )
            })
          })
      )
    })
    #test to see if I can access value of one numeric input : doesn't work
    output$value<-renderText({
      value <- input$alpha1
      #or
      #value <- input[[paste0(names_list[1],1)]]
      value
    })
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  parametresUI("test"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  parametresServer("test",names_list = names_list ,labels_list = labels_list)
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The module is supposed to use the inputs to create simulations but I've just shown an exemple that fails to display one value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing namespace `ns`.  Try this

```
parametresServer <- function(id,names_list,labels_list){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    output$parametres <-renderUI({
      number_list<-as.list(1:input$nb)
      div(class = "dynamicSI",
          lapply(1:length(names_list),function(j){
            lapply(number_list, function(i) {
              fluidRow(column(3,
                              withMathJax(numericInput(inputId=ns(paste0(names_list[j], i)), label = paste0(labels_list[j], i),value=9,min=0)
                              )),
                       column(3,
                              withMathJax(numericInput(inputId=ns(paste0("varia",names_list[j], i)), label = paste0("\\(\\sigma\\)(",labels_list[j], i,")"),value=0,min=0)
                              )),
              )
            })
          })
      )
    })
    #test to see if I can access value of one numeric input : doesn't work
    output$value<-renderText({
      value <- input$alpha1
      #or
      #value <- input[[paste0(names_list[1],1)]]
      value
    })
  })
}
```